# Is there any large scale commercial software developed base on OSGi specification?

Tags: osgi

Is there any large scale commercial software developed base on OSGi specification? I would like to see some examples and what the architecture look like.

Answer (score 1):

What is large scale? Our enterprise runs on eclipse equinox with 2.000.000+ lines of code, what is nothing uncommon. (Of course the architecture is not available to non company members)

Perhaps the glassfish j2ee app server can give you a good example. See [this](http://www.slideshare.net/wwwsahoo/osgi-java-ee-in-glassfish-3553192) slides...

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse is based on OSGi, I do not think there are that many larger code bases in a more variable environment. On top of this you find most Java EE Application Servers to be based on OSGi or heavily support it.

IT is a long time ago I had to answer this question ...